access target value by providing key Map<>
class CurrencyExchange {
  Map<String, double> exchangeRates = {
    'USD': 1.0,
    'EUR': 0.85,
    'JPY': 110.15,
    'GBP': 0.72,
    'AUD': 1.39,
    'CAD': 1.25,
    'CHF': 0.92,
    'CNY': 6.47,
    'HKD': 7.77,
    'NZD': 1.41,
  };

  exchange(double amount, String target) {
    if (exchangeRates.keys.contains(target.toUpperCase())) {
      // Here i want to access the equivalent value of the above key from Map<String, double> exchangeRates
    }
  }
}

i have written this line:
var newAmount = amount * (exchangeRates.values * 1.0);  

but it gives me this error:
The operator '*' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<double>'

What are you trying to accomplish with "this line"?

exchangeRates.values returns an iterable of every value in the map, giving you the Iterable<double>. Since you have already verified the map contains the target currency, use exchangeRates[target.toUpperCase()] to specifically get the number for that target string.
To summarize:
someMap.values returns an iterable of all values in the key/value pairs
someMap[key] returns the value associated with that key

One solution is to get the element from your map and check if it is null. This works since if you request an element that are not in the map, the [] operator will return null:
  exchange(double amount, String target) {
    double? exchangeRate = exchangeRates[target.toUpperCase()];
    if (exchangeRate != null) {
      var newAmount = amount * (exchangeRate * 1.0);
    }
  }

You can also combine this by using a pattern if you are familiar with that syntax:
  exchange(double amount, String target) {
    if (exchangeRates[target.toUpperCase()] case final exchangeRate?) {
      var newAmount = amount * (exchangeRate * 1.0);
    }
  }

